# I am trying to develop faces but i keep returning Attribute error 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: faces, error

I am trying to develop faces but i keep returning Attribute error 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

````
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Xaris\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\scripts\addons\sailFlow2_0\sail_flattener.py", line 314, in execute
    sce.sailflow_model.deStresLoops)
  File "C:\Users\Xaris\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\scripts\addons\sailFlow2_0\sail_flattener.py", line 277, in makeFlattened
    max_stress_on_edges = verts_stress_minimizer(maxDeformation, deStresLoops)
  File "C:\Users\Xaris\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\scripts\addons\sailFlow2_0\sail_flattener.py", line 187, in verts_stress_minimizer
    maxD.x = print("Destressed called---")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```
````

Comment: Hi. Please add more details to your question, like what code you are using. Remember, we don't know anything about your project. You can use the [edit] link below your question to add any appropriate images and code.

Comment: Simple python runtime errors are prob a little off topic here. This is the Same error message  with eg `y = 4` then later  `print(y.x)`  _ie_ `y` is an integer, and it does not have an `x` attribute.